# Optimize the prefix tree for string search

Tags: algorithm, scala, tree, prefix-tree

I'm thinking about improving the prefix tree. It allows me to search for the specified number of words containing the input string.

Task: We need a class that implements a list of company names by substring - from the list of all available names, output a certain number of companies that start with the entered line. It is assumed that the class will be called when filling out a form on a website/mobile application with a high RPS (Requests per second).

My Solution:

```
 class SuggestService(companyNames : Seq[String]) {

  val arrayCompany = companyNames.toArray
  val tree = getTree(Ternary.apply, 0)

  def getTree(tree: Ternary, index: Int): Ternary = {
    if(index == arrayCompany.length-1)
      return tree.insert(arrayCompany(index))

    getTree(tree.insert(arrayCompany(index)), index+1)
  }

  def suggest(input: String, numberOfSuggest : Int) : Seq[String] = {
    val result = tree.keysWithPrefix(input)
    result.take(numberOfSuggest)
  }
}
```

Tree Class:

```
sealed trait Ternary {
  def insert(key: String): Ternary = Ternary.insert(this, key, 0)

  def keysWithPrefix(prefix: String): List[String] = Ternary.keys(this, prefix)
}

case class Node(value: Option[Int], char: Char, left: Ternary, mid: Ternary, right: Ternary) extends Ternary

case object Leaf extends Ternary

object Ternary {
  def apply: Ternary = Leaf

  private def keys(root: Ternary, prefix: String): List[String] =
    get(root, prefix, 0) match {
      case None => Nil
      case Some(node) =>
        collect(node, prefix.dropRight(1))
    }

  private def collect(node: Ternary, prefix: String): List[String] =
    node match {
      case Leaf => Nil
      case node: Node if node.value.isDefined =>
        (prefix + node.char) +: (collect(node.left, prefix) ++ collect(node.mid, prefix + node.char) ++ collect(node.right, prefix))
      case node: Node =>
        collect(node.left, prefix) ++ collect(node.mid, prefix + node.char) ++ collect(node.right, prefix)
    }

  private def get(root: Ternary, prefix: String, step: Int): Option[Ternary] = root match {
    case Leaf => None
    case node: Node if node.char > prefix.charAt(step) => get(node.left, prefix, step)
    case node: Node if node.char < prefix.charAt(step) => get(node.right, prefix, step)
    case node: Node if step < prefix.length - 1 => get(node.mid, prefix, step + 1)
    case node: Node => Some(node)
  }

  private def insert(root: Ternary, key: String, step: Int): Ternary = root match {
    case Leaf =>
      val node = Node(None, key.charAt(step), Leaf, Leaf, Leaf)
      insert(node, key, step)

    case node: Node if node.char > key.charAt(step) =>
      val left = insert(node.left, key, step)
      node.copy(left = left)

    case node: Node if node.char < key.charAt(step) =>
      val right = insert(node.right, key, step)
      node.copy(right = right)

    case node: Node if step < key.length - 1 =>
      val mid = insert(node.mid, key, step + 1)
      node.copy(mid = mid)

    case node: Node =>
      node.copy(value = Some(0))
  }
}
```

The solution works fine, and it seems to promise to work very efficiently, but I am dissatisfied with it to a sufficient extent.
By the condition, we must return a list of words in an amount equal to the number of numberOfSuggest.

And I force the tree to return all the words containing input. And only then I take the required number of words from the resulting list:

```
def suggest(input: String, numberOfSuggest : Int) : Seq[String] = {
    val result = tree.keysWithPrefix(input)
    result.take(numberOfSuggest)
  }
```

I want to try to save time, and teach the tree to return a ready-made list of words limited by the number of numberOfSuggest.

Experiment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/m0MxnlChT0GkpGJIBnNnUQ

Comment: What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: Now the algorithm pulls out all the words containing input from the tree. I want it to return only the number of words I specified. The required number of words is specified in the numberOfSuggest variable.

Comment: You need to modify `keys` and `collect` methods and pass there number of expected results (I suggest making it optional) and change the finishing condition to compare number of found results with number of expected results